# MIGX отказывается корректно работать

Tags: modx, migx

Возникла проблема сразу после установки, на другом хостинге расширение работает корректно, на локалке тоже не работает. Суть проблемы наглядно изложена в скриншотах.

Как я понял, MIGX не может подключить стили и корректно отобразить страницы настроек.

Пробовал переустановки расширение и очищал кеш в админке и вручную.

```
Версия MODX REVO 2.5.7
Версия MIGX 2.11
```

[image: Ошибка в настройках]
[image: Не видит стили]

Comment: Вы после переноса на локалку запускали переустановку? Перед этим очищали папку cache? Открывали тот файл который вам пишет и смотрели что там на 39-й строке?

Comment: данный проект делается изначально на хостинге, про локалку я написал про другой проект. Файл открывал, проблема в том что расширение не пожет подгрузить стили css

Comment: Тогда вот это вот как понять "на другом хостинге расширение работает корректно, на локалке тоже не работает."

Comment: на другом хостинге пробовал устанавливать migx вместе с теми же другими дополнениями, там такой проблемы не было, затем устанавливал на другом проекте на локалке migx, там была такая же проблема

Comment: Такая же проблема, чего делать то, куда копать?